# Emacs - replace some string pattern with another string pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, emacs

I need to make a js file more friendly as node.js module

It has a bunch of statements like these

```
function someFunction(jjjj){
```

and they need to be transformed into

```
exports.someFunction = function(jjjj){
```

Even better would be if there is a call to someFunction in the code
    someFunction(bla);

it would be replaced with exports.someFunction as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace-regexp`:

```
M-x replace-regexp <RET> \(function\) \(.*\)(\(.*\)){ <RET> export.\2 = \1(\3))
```

I'm not sure you can replace the codes of calling the functions, however, if there is a pattern, you could try.

Comment: Looks good. Let's mention also query-replace-regexp, which would work respective, but works step by step, permits to check/refine the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I'd handle with keyboard macros, here's how I'd do it with some comments:

1. <kbd>C-x (</kbd> start recording macro
2. <kbd>C-s</kbd>`function`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd><kbd>M-d</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd>`exports.`<kbd>C-y</kbd>`=`<kbd>M-f</kbd><kbd>C-d</kbd> this is the whole macro. Highlighted text is the text you'd type. There are spaces around `=`, but they won't show up in the markup.
3. <kbd>C-x )</kbd> end defining a macro.
4. You can now use <kbd>C-x e</kbd> to repeat the macro (note that once you see a function you don't want to export - you can simply move the point past that function definition). Or you could <kbd>C-x C-k b</kbd><kbd>C-x x</kbd> bind the macro to <kbd>C-x x</kbd> for the duration of the Emacs session, so that if you record another one, you could later re-use it.